# Access Android camera with NDK

Tags: android, c++, camera, android-ndk, hal

I have been trying to figure out how to use NDK to access camera on android using its HAL interface. 
I have downloaded all the related files from here : 
https://github.com/android/platform_hardware_libhardware/blob/master/include/hardware/camera.h

and here :

https://github.com/android/platform_system_core

it does seem like I managed to get all the relevant files but yet the project will not compile due to numerous errors, starting from problematic makefiles and ending with missing functions like this one :

```
C:/android-ndk-r10d/samples/hello-jni/jni/camera/Camera.cpp:409:55: error: 'clone_camera_metadata' was not declared in this scope
         mSettings = clone_camera_metadata(new_settings);
```

could somebody who managed to use camera HAL shed some light on this issue

thank you

Comment: This is not intended to work, as it is not a public interface.  You could spend huge amounts of time working out the details of utilizing private internal functionality, only to have your code break on another device or even after an Android upgrade on the same device.

Comment: The code is supposed to work on a dedicated device, so that would not be a problem

Comment: Then you may want to build it as part of the AOSP build system, rather than with the NDK.  Otherwise you will have to adapt out a whole set of dependencies of your dependencies.  Or you could just use the stable, supported, public java-level APIs like everyone else.

Comment: Well the thing is, that i am trying to add functionality to an already written code in ndk, so i have to do it that way. I had in mind to import just the headers and use an .so object for the camera HAL, if it is possible.

Comment: No, you don't have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 solutions for your problem :

- You can use OpenCV to get the camera current frame. OpenCV builds nicely for Android.
- Use some not-so-fancy calls to java.

Though I'd be pleased to see you succeed into using ndk code only :) (maybe check how the OpenCV guys managed to make it work)